# iptables and securing an smtp

Tags: iptables

I am trying to block all SMTP out of my network, that is not from my internal mail server address.

So i would just like to know if there could be anything i am missing or perhaps anything i could improve on my current iptable rules for my mail server.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD-SMTP-DROP: "
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s <SMTP IP HERE> --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d <SMTP IP HERE> --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 25,465,587 -s ! <SMTP IP HERE> -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 25,465,587 -s ! <SMTP IP HERE> -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-SMTP-DROP: "
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are your mail server and your firewall server identical? Traffic goes either through FORWARD (NAT traffic) or through OUTPUT (traffic of local processes), but not through both.

Comment: All of the machines are NAT Traffic that's passing through the box, so I am only using the FORWARD part.

They are separate, yes. I know i don't need to have anything on OUTPUT as its services run on the actual box itself.

Added it to be safe more than anything, i could remove them, sure.

Comment: shouldn't you rule this better in your postfix `main.cf` instead of iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your standard policy of iptables in the FORWARD-chain is `DROP` you can remove the first line.
Additionally (for more security) you can add the ingoing and outgoing interfaces of the smtp-traffic to line 3 and 4.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o <OUTGOING IF> -i <INGOING IF> -p tcp -s <SMTP IP HERE> --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -o <OUTGOING IF> -i <INGOING IF> -p tcp -d <SMTP IP HERE> --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Just add the correct interface names of the firewall. The reason for this is quite simple: IP-Addresses can easily be spoofed, but of course you can not so easily spoof the physical interface the traffic is coming in or out. Apart from that the rules seem quite ok to me. Just try if it works as you meant it to work and see if there is any unexpected behaviour.

Greatings, Darth Ravage

Comment: I was thinking of using the in and out interfaces. I have 5 physical interfaces and 12 virtual interfaces, but those have already been setup and are just used for internal things.

Thanks Darth Ravage, i will change accordingly. I may have to change the default rule of FORWARD chain to DROP though.

Answer (score 0):

If your default policy for the FORWARD chain is ACCEPT:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25  -o [outgoing iface]  -s ! [internal smtp ip] \ 
-m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Ideally your default policy should be set to DROP.  That will only require you to allow out traffic that you want, everything that you don't specifically allow will be denied.

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP  # set FORWARD policy to DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -o [outgoing iface] -s [internal smtp ip] \
-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You should always include TCP state in your rules `-m state --state` and if you're using the FORWARD table you need to define a rule's direction by using the incoming/outgoing interface option, `-i` & `-o`.  Without defining an incoming or outgoing interface, these rules will be ambiguous and won't apply to a certain direction.